# Working with Activiti BPM

Tags: java, business-process-management, activiti

I'm a newbie in Activiti BPM and I have a conceptual question about to work with it: today I have some EJB facades that handle business logic and do some validations, and these facades are called from an web app. The question is: instead, should I call the Activiti services or should my EJB services call it (Activiti) internally from the web layer? What about if I call the Activiti services and a business validation is thrown? How can I catch the exception and show the messages in the web app screen?

I'd like to know the best way do work consistently with Activiti.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should call your services from Activiti because you can completely manage your workflow logic in Activiti without restricting yourself to provided services.

Activiti throws ActivitiException and you can catch in your web layer. In addition you can use Boundary Error Events in your process models.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from you question is that, you have a BPM process that is carried out in Activiti and you want to call that from your Web Application.

The reality is Activiti provides very easy and adequate APIs to meet your requirement. You can easily `deploy` your BPM process in your server, where your Web Application runs, and make a call to that process from the application.

Please go the REST APIs and respective Java APIs [here](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#N12B3B).

Go through its user guide , then configure and deploy the process and call it from your Web Application.